# Using awk to parse for conditions over multiple lines? (ifconfig output)

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk, ifconfig

I'm trying to parse ifconfig output with awk.

Right now my script is:

```
# Setup

ifconfig > ip.txt

ans=$(cat ip.txt | awk '$1 == "inet" {print $2}')

#output

echo "Here are your IPs:"

echo"$ans"
```

Output:

```
Here are your IPs:

192.168.1.1
192.168.2.1
```

What I want is an output more like

```
Here are your IPs: 

eth0 192.168.1.1
wlan0 192.168.2.1
```

But `awk` only parses by line, which is why I'm using `inet` as the `$1` identifier for `awk`. As you know, `ifconfig` has multiple lines between the interface name and the IP address, so I can't increase that `$2` to however many words away the address is.

I think the solution has to do with using `RS` or possibly using `sed` instead of `awk`. No luck using `RS` to change how `awk` sees lines.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: But why `ifconfig`? It's deprecated and replaced by the `ip` tool, which conveniently has an option for outputting one line per interface just for this.

Comment: True, but same issue for me:


`6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000

    link/ether 00:15:5d:ca:f4:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

    inet 172.18.236.6/20 brd 172.18.239.255 scope global eth0`

Actual address is on a different line, so my current setup wouldn't be able to parse that info.

Comment: It has an **option** for one-line output: `ip -o addr` or `ip -oneline addr`

Comment: @muru Thank you. When I change to using that, awk doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: What does that mean? Did they release a new version of awk with sentience?

Comment: @muru haha, no, it means I am very bad at this and need to fiddle with it more. I appreciate your helping me out

Comment: You probably just need to check the fields you're using to compare and output

Answer (score 1):

Well, if really wanna use ifconfig, you can do this:

```
# Setup
ifconfig > ip.txt

# Parse the output
ans=$(cat ip.txt | awk '/^[^ ]/{iface=$1} /inet / {print iface, $2}')

# Output
echo "Here are your IPs:"
echo "$ans"
```

Comment: `cat` is not needed here ... i.e. `awk '...' ip.txt`

Comment: yeah, easier is just using ```ans=$(awk '/^[^ ]/{iface=$1} /inet / {print iface, $2}' ip.txt)```

Comment: I'm new to this site, so my reputation won't let me comment, but it will let me answer... The answer Vic gate is good, but I just wanted to point out that you don't need the intermediate file ip.txt, because awk can read that text on stdin: echo "Here are your IPs:" ifconfig | awk '/^[^ ]/{iface=$1} /inet / {print iface, $2}'